# qt treewidget widget item QCheckBox alignment

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTreeWidget` where I insert different widgets (`QDoubleSpinBox`,`QSpinBox`,`QCheckBox`...)

```
QTreeWidget *t = ui->treeWidget;
QTreeWidgetItem *item = new QTreeWidgetItem();

int c = 0;
QDoubleSpinBox *dspb = new QDoubleSpinBox();
t->setItemWidget(item, c++, dspb);

QSpinBox *spb = new QSpinBox();
t->setItemWidget(item, c++, spb);

QCheckBox *cb = new QCheckBox();
t->setItemWidget(item, c++, cb);

t->addTopLevelItem(item);
```

However, the `cb` widget looks wired since the checkbox is aligned to the left. I would like to see it aligned in the center.

**Q: How can I change the checkbox to appear in the middle of the TreeWidget cell?**

I need to be able to access the `cb` item again later. Currently, I use the following code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *itm = t->topLevelItem(0);
bool checked  = qobject_cast<QCheckBox *>(t->itemWidget(itm,c++))->checkState() == Qt::Checked;
```

If I need to do some workaround to get the central alignment going, how can I access the `cb` object then?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

```
cb->setStyleSheet("margin-left:50%; margin-right:50%;");
```

works!